# Matplotlib set minor tick at a specific date

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am trying to set a minor tick in Matplotlib at a specific date to indicate a change at that date, however I can not seem to find a way to implement that.
I want my minor_locator to only be at the date 1991-01-01.

My code:

```
fig,ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(12,8))
ax.plot_date(texas_third_final.index,texas_third_final['Value'],'-')

ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(dates.YearLocator())
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(dates.DateFormatter('%Y'))

ax.xaxis.set_minor_locator(dates.YearLocator())
ax.xaxis.set_minor_formatter(dates.DateFormatter('\n\n%Y'))

fig.autofmt_xdate()
plt.tight_layout()
```

Chart Layout and code:

[image: Chart Layout and code]

Comment: `ax.set_xticks(dates.date2num(datetime(1991,1,1)), minor=True)`

Comment: This doesn't work for me. I keep getting "object of type 'float' has no len()"

Comment: I suspect its rather `ax.set_xticks([dates.date2num(datetime(1991,1,1))], minor=True)` then. Note that without [mcve], one cannot test.